# How to create a list of tcbtheorems

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, tcolorbox

I am trying to get something similar to `\listoftheorems` but for `tcbtheorem`s; ideally a list for each specific type of `tcbtheorem` in case I need to list another type later. There is probably a simple command out there, but I could not find it.
And how do I modify the code so that the title of the `tcolorbox` is listed as well:

List of Questions:

- Question 1.1: some question
- Question 1.2: some other question

I tried adapting the code from [tcolorbox - list of listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86711/tcolorbox-list-of-listings) and from [How can I add my tcolorbox to my table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148852/how-can-i-add-my-tcolorbox-to-my-table-of-contents)
but I could not even make the theorems become part of the list, so I just got an empty list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--  ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
    },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{questionbox}{Question}{thmbox}{qst}

\begin{document}
\tcblistof[\section*]{qst}{List of Questions}

\chapter{foo}

\section{bla}

\begin{questionbox}{some question}{}
the answer goes here
\end{questionbox}

\begin{questionbox}{some other question}{}
the answer goes here
\end{questionbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `list inside=qst` option must be used in the `init` option list of `\newtcbtheorem`.

This enables the list feature and informs `tcolorbox` that list entries shall be written to a `.qst` file and by default the `title` will be used, unless `list entry=...` is explicitly used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--  ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
    },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,list inside={qst}]{questionbox}{Question}{thmbox}{qst}

\begin{document}
\tcblistof[\section*]{qst}{List of Questions}

\chapter{foo}

\section{bla}

\begin{questionbox}{some question}{}
the answer goes here
\end{questionbox}

\begin{questionbox}{some other question}{}
the answer goes here
\end{questionbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So if I, let's say, wanted to have the contents of the theorem listed instead of the title, what would I need to change? In other words, what are the parameters that `list entry=` can take? And where in the code do I put `list entry=`? Next to `list inside=`?