# \listoftheorems and its alternative with tcbtheorems not displaying,

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, theorems, tcolorbox

i tried to to get a list of definitions (theorems) at the end of my document in the appednix. Unfortunality, the list is empty. I tried to use [the description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329134/how-to-create-a-list-of-tcbtheorems) but it does not work (for me). The "Definitionsverzeichnis", here marked with "List of Questions" should look like this: [image]I do not find the mistake(s) and im searching for 4 hours no, so its a little bit frustrating.

Bevor using tcbtheorems I used mdtheorems, where it was no problem to get a list of theorems. However, now it wont work...

Perhaps someone could help me because tcbtheorems look really nice and i just want to keep them.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt, listof=totocnumbered, toc=bibliographynumbered,appendixprefix = on]{scrartcl} %scrartcl  article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% preamble   
\usepackage{tcolorbox}   
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}   
\tcbuselibrary{skins}   
\usepackage{amsthm}   
\usepackage{thmtools}   
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}



% definiton   
\tcbset{    
 defstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,fontupper=\slshape,arc=0mm,colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black},    
 theostyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,colback=red!10!white,colframe=red!75!black},    
}   
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection,crefname={definition}{definitions}, list inside={qst}]{Definition}{defstyle}{def}{qst}    
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=Definition, crefname={theorem}{theorems}, list inside={qst}]{Theorem}{theostyle}{theo}{qst}       
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=Definition,crefname={corollary}{corollaries}]{Corollary}{Corollary}{theostyle}{cor}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=Definition]{definition}{Definition}{theorem style=plain,enhanced,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=yellow!20!white,coltitle=red!50!black,fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,fontupper=\itshape,drop fuzzy shadow=blue!50!black!50!white,boxrule=0.4pt}{theo}

% theorem 
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}

\begin{document}   
\section{hello}   
\subsection{world}   



\section{new section}    
\subsection{new subsection for definitons}    


% example definition     
\begin{definition}{Hello}{labelHEY}%
\newline
a nice definition
\end{definition}

% example theorem
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10!white,colframe=red!60!black,sharp corners=all ]
\begin{satz}
this is not a proof, just a theorem
\end{satz}
\end{tcolorbox}


% appendix, 


\tcblistof[\section]{qst}{Definitionsverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like: [image]

THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH for your help and your time.

Comment: You have defined "Definition" and "definition" and use the second one into your text, but this one doesn't have `list inside={qst}`. Therefore it's normal that it doesn't appear in list of theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load lots of packages for the same thing. This only makes the code very confusing. Stick to one and then check the documentation so that you get the arguments right.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt, listof=totocnumbered, toc=bibliographynumbered,appendixprefix = on]{scrartcl} %scrartcl  article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% preamble
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% definiton
\tcbset{
 defstyle/.style=
  {fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,fontupper=\slshape,arc=0mm,colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black},
 theostyle/.style=
  {fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,colback=red!10!white,colframe=red!75!black},
}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection,
               crefname={definition}{definitions}, 
               list inside={qst}] %init
               {definition} %name
               {Definition} %display
               {defstyle}   %options
               {def}        %prefix
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=definition, crefname={theorem}{theorems}, 
               list inside={qst}]
               {theorem}
               {Theorem}
               {theostyle}
               {theo}


\begin{document}
\section{hello}
\subsection{world}



\section{new section}
\subsection{new subsection for definitons}


% example definition
\begin{definition}{Hello Definition}{labelHEY}%
a nice definition
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}{Hello Theorem}{labelHEY}%
a nice theorem
\end{theorem}


\tcblistof[\section]{qst}{Definitionsverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

[image]